# php mysqli_query function seems to run twice

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

This is a custom function for my site where I need to show different URL's inside an iframe. I only want to show each url once to the user so I am first creating an array of available urls, then an array of already seen urls and finally compare the two to create a new array for urls to be shown. I then need to echo the first element of this array into the iframe.

The problem seems to lie within the foreach function where I execute the entry into the database `$entry = "INSERT INTO views VALUES ('', '$currentUsername', '$urlToShow')";`

I tried with many different approaches, but no matter what I do I get two urls from the `$urlsToShow` array added into the database and only one of them gets echoed inside my iframe. The result is that every other site simply gets skipped altogether and the user never sees them.

I have print_r'd the `$urlsToShow` to make sure it is an array and I did the same to make sure `$urlToShow` is not an array.

I'm not even sure if this is a php problem any more...

Here is the code:

```
function get_urls() {
    require 'config.php';
    global $con;
    global $currentUsername;
    $con = mysqli_connect($hostname, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
    $query = "SELECT site_url FROM sites WHERE site_url IS NOT NULL";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    // Get all the site urls into one array
        $siteUrls = array();
        $index = 0;
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $siteUrls[$index] = $row['site_url'];
            $index++;
        }
    $query2 = "SELECT site_url FROM views WHERE user = '$currentUsername' AND site_url IS NOT NULL";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($con, $query2);
    // Get urls the user has already seen into another array
        $seenUrls = array();
        $index = 0;
        while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
            $seenUrls[$index] = $row2['site_url'];
            $index++;
        }
    // Compare the two arrays and create yet another array of urls to actually show
    $urlsToShow = array_diff($siteUrls, $seenUrls);
    if (!empty($urlsToShow)) {
        // Echo the url to show for the iframe within browse.php and add an entry to the database that the user has seen this site
        foreach ($urlsToShow as $urlToShow) {
            $entry = "INSERT INTO views VALUES ('', '$currentUsername', '$urlToShow')";
            mysqli_query($con,$entry);
            echo $urlToShow;
            break;
        }
    }
    // Show the allSeen file when all the ads are seen
    else {echo 'includes/allSeen.php';}
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

**EDIT**

I took the advice [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29328007/4086533) and made the function smaller, but the same result is still happening. Two urls get added to the views table, but only the first of the two gets echoed in the iframe.

```
function get_urls() {
    require 'config.php';
    global $con;
    global $currentUsername;
    $con = mysqli_connect($hostname, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
    $query = "SELECT sites.site_url FROM sites LEFT JOIN views ON views.site_url=sites.site_url AND views.user='$currentUsername' WHERE sites.site_url IS NOT NULL AND views.site_url IS NULL";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    $urlsToShow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    if (!empty($urlsToShow)) {
        $urlToShow = $urlsToShow['site_url'];
        echo $urlToShow;
        $entry = "INSERT INTO views VALUES ('', '$currentUsername', '$urlToShow')";
        mysqli_query($con,$entry);
    }
    else {echo 'includes/allSeen.php';}
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

**EDIT 2**

I have also tried with php readfile(); function because I thought perhaps it's the iframe that's causing this. But no, same result. Maybe I'm calling the function wrong?

```
<iframe src="<?php get_urls();?>"/>
```

**EDIT 3**

I have also tried echo'ing the iframe html tags within the function along with the urlToShow to see if that makes a difference. Nope, it didn't.

Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me two days to finally figure out the actual cause for this. Apparently there is a bug in Firefox and in Chrome too (because I tested it with both just in case).

**tldr;**

If you leave the `<link>` tags `href` empty the scripts will run twice

Example (don't do it):

`<link rel="Shortcut Icon" href="" type="image/x-icon"/>`

The `href` needs to have a value!

You can read more about it here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=489115

Comment: So we run into an issue here that I am not sure how to resolve (MODS, please chime in).  We have a successful and repeatable solution to the actual problem experienced, but the initial question does not include the actual offending code.  Is it sufficient to simply add the offending code to the OP (possibly invalidating previous comments/answers)? Should the OP be reworded to suit?  Should off topic answers (once the offending code is added) be removed?  How should this be handled? (@ynef, don't do any of what I said, let's get some feedback first).

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to the PHP Error Log?  My path to debug would be two-fold:

1. Add `static $calls = 0;` to the top of the function, and add a line just under it `error_log('Called '.(++$called).' time(s).');`.  This will tell you if it is being called more than one times as part of the same request.
2. If you determine it is being called multiple times in the same request, try logging the first entry in debug_backtrace.

Place the following at the beginning of the function to log the location the function was called from.

```
$trace = current(debug_backtrace());
error_log("Called by {$trace['file']}:{$trace['line']}");
```

Combined, these two things should identify your problem.

Comment: I tried adding debug_print_backtrace(); right before the mysqli_query and I think it only runs once because the result was #0 get_urls called at...

Comment: The key to this is to utilize the error log. I suspect this is getting called after output is sent, or on another request.

Comment: I managed to find out the problem on my own. Thanks for the help. I really appreciate it!